# XPath to select value of XMLNS attribute in T-SQL

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath

I have an XML document that looks like this. It may be that it's invalid (I didn't create it!)

```
<ns:url xmlns:ns="http://www.urlone.com/" xmlns:news="http://www.urltwo.com/">
.. node tree
</ns:url>
```

I need to build a T-SQL Query to extract the value of the xmlns:news attribute and update it. This requires XPath. But all the queries I've attempted so far fail with an error similar to:

> XPath expression uses unbound namespace prefix xmlns

Is is possible to select and update this node given the XML format? If so, how?

Cheers,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value you can use the [OPENXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226522%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) edge table.

```
declare @XML xml = '
<ns:url xmlns:ns="http://www.urlone.com/" xmlns:news="http://www.urltwo.com/">
</ns:url>'

declare @idoc int

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc output, @XML

select X1.[text]
from openxml(@idoc, '*') as X1
  inner join openxml(@idoc, '*') as X2
    on X1.parentid = X2.id
where X2.localname = 'news' and -- Attribute name
      X2.prefix = 'xmlns' and   -- Namespace
      X2.parentid = 0           -- Attribute on root

exec sp_xml_removedocument @idoc
```

I don't know of a way to update the URL other than recreating the XML or to use [string manipulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The openxml pointer wasn;t useful but in the end I just got the job done by string manipulation. Slow and inelegant, but effective.

Answer (score 0):

In the XPath data model, namespace declarations translate into namespace nodes, not attribute nodes. so the XPath expression to find the value of the news namespace is

```
/*/namespace::news
```

Comment: This is technically correct, but sadly not available in the t-sql implementation of XPath/XQuery.